# Defintions for class within a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an issue defining the following JavaScript function in TypeScript.

Here is what I have (and want the TS definition file to support):

### myfile.ts:

```
this._scanCallback = new android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback({
    onLeScan: function (device: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, rssi: number, scanRecord: Array<number>) {
    // FUNCTIONALITY ...
    }
})
```

Here is my existing definition file, but the `onLeScan()` isn't working.

### def.d.ts:

```
export module android {
    export class bluetooth {

        export class BluetoothAdapter extends java.lang.Object {

            static xyz: number;
            public abcd(): boolean;

        }
        export namespace BluetoothAdapter {
            export class LeScanCallback(
                onLeScan(device: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, rssi: number, scanRecord: Array<number>): void;
            ){}
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to access the `android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback()` function, with input parameters requiring an `onLeScan` callback function such that the snippet in **myfile.ts** passes ts compilation. Currently I am getting:

> [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
>   constructor android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback(): android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback

Any suggestions as to what my definition should look like would be much appreciated.

Comment: The definition file snippet you have here doesn't even parse. What is the actual content of the file?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I know the snippet doesn't work (hence the question) ... I have added some more context to try and illustrate the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to breakdown your problem into manageable chunks. From the innermost to the outermost, you need:

- a class or interface which defines a method `onLeScan()`,
- a class named `LeScanCallback` that takes an instance of the above class or interface in its constructor,
- a module or namespace named `BluetoothAdapter` which contains the LeScanCallback class, and
- apparently, a class named `BluetoothAdapter` with a couple of random properties.

Here's how I would tackle this. Your mileage may vary.

```
export module android.bluetooth {
    export interface BluetoothDevice {}
    export class BluetoothAdapter extends java.lang.Object {
        static xyz: number;
        public abcd(): boolean;
    }
}
export module android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter {
    export interface LeScanCallbackArgument {
        onLeScan(device: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, rssi: number, scanRecord: Array<number>);
    }
    export class LeScanCallback {
        constructor(callback: LeScanCallbackArgument) {}
    }
}

this._scanCallback = new android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback({
    onLeScan: function (device: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, rssi: number, scanRecord: Array<number>) {
    // FUNCTIONALITY ...
    }
})
```

This compiles (except for missing reference to `java.lang.Object`) at the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20export%20module%20android.bluetooth%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09export%20interface%20BluetoothDevice%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20BluetoothAdapter%20extends%20java.lang.Object%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20xyz%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20abcd()%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20module%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20LeScanCallbackArgument%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onLeScan(device%3A%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice%2C%20rssi%3A%20number%2C%20scanRecord%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20export%20class%20LeScanCallback%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(callback%3A%20LeScanCallbackArgument)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this._scanCallback%20%3D%20new%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onLeScan%3A%20function%20(device%3A%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice%2C%20rssi%3A%20number%2C%20scanRecord%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20FUNCTIONALITY%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A).